# Any way to speed up price indexer

Tags: php, magento

In a shop we are maintaining it takes ages before the price indexes are up to date. While analyzing the process I've noticed that the bundle price indexer is using a query that takes 40 seconds to execute, which is way too long if you ask me. This query will be repeated for about 8 times so no wonder why the indexing problem is so slow.

Is there something I can do about it. If analyzed the query via Explain and that gave no optimizations that could be made. Are there any other options? I'd love to hear them.

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT `e`.`entity_id`, 
       `cg`.`customer_group_id`, 
       `cw`.`website_id`, 
       IF(IF(Ifnull(tas_tax_class_id.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_tax_class_id.value, 
             tad_tax_class_id.value) IS NOT NULL, IF( 
       Ifnull(tas_tax_class_id.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_tax_class_id.value, 
                                                  tad_tax_class_id.value), 0) 
       AS
       `tax_class_id`, 
       1 
       AS `price_type`, 
       IF(IF(ta_special_from_date.value IS NULL, 1, IF( 
             ta_special_from_date.value <= cwd.website_date, 1, 0)) > 0 
          AND IF(ta_special_to_date.value IS NULL, 1, IF( 
                  ta_special_to_date.value >= cwd.website_date, 1, 0)) > 0 
          AND IF(Ifnull(tas_special_price.value_id, -1) > 0, 
              tas_special_price.value, 
                  tad_special_price.value) > 0 
          AND IF(Ifnull(tas_special_price.value_id, -1) > 0, 
              tas_special_price.value, 
                  tad_special_price.value) < 100, IF( 
       Ifnull(tas_special_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_price.value, 
                                                  tad_special_price.value), 0) 
       AS
       `special_price`, 
       tp.min_price 
       AS `tier_percent`, 
       IF(IF(Ifnull(tas_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_price.value, 
          tad_price.value) IS
          NULL, 0, IF(Ifnull(tas_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_price.value, 
                   tad_price.value)) 
       AS `orig_price`, 
       IF(IF(IF(ta_special_from_date.value IS NULL, 1, IF( 
                   ta_special_from_date.value <= cwd.website_date, 1, 0)) > 0 
             AND IF(ta_special_to_date.value IS NULL, 1, IF( 
                     ta_special_to_date.value >= cwd.website_date, 1, 0)) > 0 
             AND IF(Ifnull(tas_special_price.value_id, -1) > 0, 
                 tas_special_price.value, 
                     tad_special_price.value) > 0 
             AND IF(Ifnull(tas_special_price.value_id, -1) > 0, 
                 tas_special_price.value, 
                     tad_special_price.value) < 100, 
          IF( 
             Ifnull(tas_special_price.value_id, -1) > 0, 
          tas_special_price.value, 
                                                     tad_special_price.value), 0 
          ) > 0, 
       Round( 
       IF(Ifnull(tas_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_price.value, tad_price.value) 
       * ( IF( 
       IF 
       (ta_special_from_date.value IS NULL, 1, IF( 
             ta_special_from_date.value <= 
             cwd.website_date, 1, 0)) > 0 
             AND IF(ta_special_to_date.value IS NULL, 1, IF( 
                     ta_special_to_date.value >= cwd.website_date, 1, 0)) > 0 
             AND IF(Ifnull(tas_special_price.value_id, -1) > 0, 
                 tas_special_price.value, 
                     tad_special_price.value) > 0 
             AND IF(Ifnull(tas_special_price.value_id, -1) > 0, 
                 tas_special_price.value, 
                     tad_special_price.value) < 100, 
           IF( 
             Ifnull(tas_special_price.value_id, -1) > 0, 
           tas_special_price.value, 
                                                     tad_special_price.value), 0 
           ) / 100 
       ), 4), IF(Ifnull(tas_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_price.value, 
              tad_price.value)) 
                       AS `price`, 
       IF(IF(IF(ta_special_from_date.value IS NULL, 1, IF( 
                   ta_special_from_date.value <= cwd.website_date, 1, 0)) > 0 
             AND IF(ta_special_to_date.value IS NULL, 1, IF( 
                     ta_special_to_date.value >= cwd.website_date, 1, 0)) > 0 
             AND IF(Ifnull(tas_special_price.value_id, -1) > 0, 
                 tas_special_price.value, 
                     tad_special_price.value) > 0 
             AND IF(Ifnull(tas_special_price.value_id, -1) > 0, 
                 tas_special_price.value, 
                     tad_special_price.value) < 100, 
          IF( 
             Ifnull(tas_special_price.value_id, -1) > 0, 
          tas_special_price.value, 
                                                     tad_special_price.value), 0 
          ) > 0, 
       Round( 
       IF(Ifnull(tas_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_price.value, tad_price.value) 
       * ( IF( 
       IF 
       (ta_special_from_date.value IS NULL, 1, IF( 
             ta_special_from_date.value <= 
             cwd.website_date, 1, 0)) > 0 
             AND IF(ta_special_to_date.value IS NULL, 1, IF( 
                     ta_special_to_date.value >= cwd.website_date, 1, 0)) > 0 
             AND IF(Ifnull(tas_special_price.value_id, -1) > 0, 
                 tas_special_price.value, 
                     tad_special_price.value) > 0 
             AND IF(Ifnull(tas_special_price.value_id, -1) > 0, 
                 tas_special_price.value, 
                     tad_special_price.value) < 100, 
           IF( 
             Ifnull(tas_special_price.value_id, -1) > 0, 
           tas_special_price.value, 
                                                     tad_special_price.value), 0 
           ) / 100 
       ), 4), IF(Ifnull(tas_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_price.value, 
              tad_price.value)) 
                       AS `min_price`, 
       IF(IF(IF(ta_special_from_date.value IS NULL, 1, IF( 
                   ta_special_from_date.value <= cwd.website_date, 1, 0)) > 0 
             AND IF(ta_special_to_date.value IS NULL, 1, IF( 
                     ta_special_to_date.value >= cwd.website_date, 1, 0)) > 0 
             AND IF(Ifnull(tas_special_price.value_id, -1) > 0, 
                 tas_special_price.value, 
                     tad_special_price.value) > 0 
             AND IF(Ifnull(tas_special_price.value_id, -1) > 0, 
                 tas_special_price.value, 
                     tad_special_price.value) < 100, 
          IF( 
             Ifnull(tas_special_price.value_id, -1) > 0, 
          tas_special_price.value, 
                                                     tad_special_price.value), 0 
          ) > 0, 
       Round( 
       IF(Ifnull(tas_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_price.value, tad_price.value) 
       * ( IF( 
       IF 
       (ta_special_from_date.value IS NULL, 1, IF( 
             ta_special_from_date.value <= 
             cwd.website_date, 1, 0)) > 0 
             AND IF(ta_special_to_date.value IS NULL, 1, IF( 
                     ta_special_to_date.value >= cwd.website_date, 1, 0)) > 0 
             AND IF(Ifnull(tas_special_price.value_id, -1) > 0, 
                 tas_special_price.value, 
                     tad_special_price.value) > 0 
             AND IF(Ifnull(tas_special_price.value_id, -1) > 0, 
                 tas_special_price.value, 
                     tad_special_price.value) < 100, 
           IF( 
             Ifnull(tas_special_price.value_id, -1) > 0, 
           tas_special_price.value, 
                                                     tad_special_price.value), 0 
           ) / 100 
       ), 4), IF(Ifnull(tas_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_price.value, 
              tad_price.value)) 
                       AS `max_price`, 
       IF(tp.min_price IS NOT NULL, Round(IF(Ifnull(tas_price.value_id, -1) > 0, 
                                          tas_price.value, tad_price.value) 
                                                                       - ( 
                                          IF(Ifnull(tas_price.value_id, -1) > 0, 
                                          tas_price.value, tad_price.value) * ( 
                                          tp.min_price / 100 ) ), 4), NULL) 
       AS
       `tier_price`, 
       IF(tp.min_price IS NOT NULL, Round(IF(Ifnull(tas_price.value_id, -1) > 0, 
                                          tas_price.value, tad_price.value) 
                                                                       - ( 
                                          IF(Ifnull(tas_price.value_id, -1) > 0, 
                                          tas_price.value, tad_price.value) * ( 
                                          tp.min_price / 100 ) ), 4), NULL) 
       AS
       `base_tier` 
FROM   `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` 
       CROSS JOIN `customer_group` AS `cg` 
       CROSS JOIN `core_website` AS `cw` 
       INNER JOIN `core_store_group` AS `csg` 
               ON csg.group_id = cw.default_group_id 
       INNER JOIN `core_store` AS `cs` 
               ON cs.store_id = csg.default_store_id 
       INNER JOIN `catalog_product_website` AS `pw` 
               ON pw.product_id = e.entity_id 
                  AND pw.website_id = cw.website_id 
       INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_website` AS `cwd` 
               ON cw.website_id = cwd.website_id 
       LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_index_tier_price` AS `tp` 
              ON tp.entity_id = e.entity_id 
                 AND tp.website_id = cw.website_id 
                 AND tp.customer_group_id = cg.customer_group_id 
       INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tad_status` 
               ON tad_status.entity_id = e.entity_id 
                  AND tad_status.attribute_id = 80 
                  AND tad_status.store_id = 0 
       LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tas_status` 
              ON tas_status.entity_id = e.entity_id 
                 AND tas_status.attribute_id = 80 
                 AND tas_status.store_id = cs.store_id 
       LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tad_tax_class_id` 
              ON tad_tax_class_id.entity_id = e.entity_id 
                 AND tad_tax_class_id.attribute_id = 81 
                 AND tad_tax_class_id.store_id = 0 
       LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tas_tax_class_id` 
              ON tas_tax_class_id.entity_id = e.entity_id 
                 AND tas_tax_class_id.attribute_id = 81 
                 AND tas_tax_class_id.store_id = cs.store_id 
       INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `ta_price_type` 
               ON ta_price_type.entity_id = e.entity_id 
                  AND ta_price_type.attribute_id = 470 
                  AND ta_price_type.store_id = 0 
       LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `tad_price` 
              ON tad_price.entity_id = e.entity_id 
                 AND tad_price.attribute_id = 60 
                 AND tad_price.store_id = 0 
       LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `tas_price` 
              ON tas_price.entity_id = e.entity_id 
                 AND tas_price.attribute_id = 60 
                 AND tas_price.store_id = cs.store_id 
       LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `tad_special_price` 
              ON tad_special_price.entity_id = e.entity_id 
                 AND tad_special_price.attribute_id = 61 
                 AND tad_special_price.store_id = 0 
       LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `tas_special_price` 
              ON tas_special_price.entity_id = e.entity_id 
                 AND tas_special_price.attribute_id = 61 
                 AND tas_special_price.store_id = cs.store_id 
       LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `ta_special_from_date` 
              ON ta_special_from_date.entity_id = e.entity_id 
                 AND ta_special_from_date.attribute_id = 62 
                 AND ta_special_from_date.store_id = 0 
       LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `ta_special_to_date` 
              ON ta_special_to_date.entity_id = e.entity_id 
                 AND ta_special_to_date.attribute_id = 63 
                 AND ta_special_to_date.store_id = 0 
       INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `ciss` 
               ON ciss.product_id = e.entity_id 
                  AND ciss.website_id = cw.website_id 
WHERE  ( e.type_id = 'bundle' ) 
       AND ( IF(Ifnull(tas_status.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_status.value, 
             tad_status.value) = 1 ) 
       AND ( ta_price_type.value = 1 ) 
       AND ( e.entity_id IN( 99, 228, 248, 249, 
                             251, 252, 257, 263, 275 ) ) 
       AND ( ciss.stock_status = 1 )
```

Comment: Your best optimization would be not to use Magento at all. If you own a SQL-server-cluster Magento may be used in a performant way. In any other way you should use a faster shop-system. The query above is just one example out of hundreds of long-lasting queries within Magento. A 40 second query is really fast for that shop system on a shared host.

Comment: Magento should not be run on a shared host.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a thread that explains how to reduce that specific query. I havent spent time trying it my self, when i do i would look to make the fix as a module, but the quicker way to do it is by placing a copy of the file in the 'code/local' folder.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/38818/P90/#t367525